# Hyperopt Change Values of Trials() Object maually; Warm Start Hyperopt

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameters, automl, hyperopt

I search for a possibility to Warmstart Hyperopt. 
One way would be to manually fill the List `Trials.trials` with hyperameters 
This is acutally possible, yet i wonder if this really influences the optimization, or if this Trials.trials is just the visable Part of the Trials Object, and Hyperopt.

Comment: apperently is the trials.trials not the information containing part. overwriting it with different values does not influence the values inside the tpe.py

Comment: the refresh() function of base.py changes the values auf trials.trials back to its originally set value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trials.trials list does not contain all information !!
one also has to change the trials._dynamic_trials because of the resfresh function in baye.py, which updates the data from trials.trials with the data from trials._dynamic_trials

In general warmstarting should be possible. I created a fake trials object in the size of my warmstart states by calling fmin on a fresh trials object with some arbitrary search space and objective function.
After this the trials object may be changed by iterating over the lenght of trials.trials and setting the values
like so:

```
list_of_coldstart_dict = [one_possible_and_evaluation,second_possible_and_evaluation,...]
fake_space = {
'test': 2-hp.loguniform('test_02',0.001, 0.1)
}
def Objective(params):
    return {"loss":0, 'status': STATUS_OK}
trials = Trials()
fmin(Objective,fake_space,
    algo=partial(tpe.suggest, n_startup_jobs=len(list_of_coldstart_dict)), max_evals=len(list_of_coldstart_dicts), 
        trials=new_trials,verbose=1)

for in in range(len(trials.trials):
    trials.trials[i] = list_of_coldstart_dict[i]
    trials._dynamic_trials[i] = list_of_coldstart_dict[i]
    trials.results[i] = trials.trials[i]['result']
```

beware to maintain the neccecary structure of the dict of dicts inside trials.trials[i]